# AWS IAM - Deny certain EC2 actions based on resource tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to construct an IAM policy that allows any EC2 action if the resource has a specific resource tag (Development), but deny if the tag is a different value (Production). Here's what I have so far.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Environment": "Development"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Environment": "Production"
            }
        }
    }

]}
```

I have an AMI with the resource tag "Environment" and value "Production", yet I am still allowed to deregister it without an issue. What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated: 2021-10]

It seems to be the case that `ec2:DeregisterImage` now supports both `aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey}` and `ec2:ResourceTag/${TagKey}`.

[Original: 2019-02]

The `ec2:DeregisterImage` action does not currently support `ec2:ResourceTag/${TagKey}`.

See [Actions Defined for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-actions-as-permissions) which provides a list of conditions supported on EC2 actions.